# How do you assert OnActionExecuting when unit testing your attribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have an ActionFilterAttribute. I want to unit test it's on `OnActionExecuting()` method. I was able to mock the HttpContext, ActionParameters and other required objects using RhinoMock.

Here is how it looks like

```
public class AuthorizeABCAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var abc = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-GOD-MODE"];
        var ip = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
        var email = filterContext.ActionParameters["EmailAddress"] as string;

        if (ISALLOWED(abc, ip, email))
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        else
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

So depending on a condition access is allowed or else a 404 is given.

So in my unit test how do I assert for these two different condition ?

Comment: Why not just create an AuthorizeABCAttribute instance in your test, call its OnActionExecuting and afterwards, test the ActionExecutingContext.Result value?

Comment: What does `ISALLOWED` determine? Assuming that's part of the subject under test, shouldn't you have a list of scenario that will cause it to either return `true` or `false`? If so, isn't it simply a matter of setting those things on the `filterContext` being passed to this method?